# Elasticsearch filter range on nested objects

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I have an object `PurchaseOrder` that has a `List<VendorStatus> VendorStatuses`, `VendorStatus` has an `EstimatedShipDate` column. I need to filter a purchase order by the latest `EstimatedShipDate`. How can I do this?

I've tried:

```
Filter<PurchaseOrder>.Range(r => r
    .OnField(x => x.VendorStatuses.OrderByDescending(v => v.StatusUpdateDate).First().EstimatedShipDate)
    .GreaterOrEquals(fromDate)
    .LowerOrEquals(toDate));
```

and

```
var f = Filter<PurchaseOrder>.Range(r => r
    .OnField("VendorStatuses.EstimatedShipDate")
    .GreaterOrEquals(fromDate)
    .LowerOrEquals(toDate));
```

and

```
var newFilter = Filter<PurchaseOrder>.Nested(nfd => nfd.Path(x => x.VendorStatuses.First().EstimatedShipDate))
    .Filter(f2 => f2.Range(x => x.OnField(f => f.VendorStatuses.First().EstimatedShipDate)
    .GreaterOrEquals(fromDate)
    .LowerOrEquals(toDate))));
```

But none of these worked. How can I do this?

I'm not even able to get the date range working when running against elastic directly. The following query returns no results even though when using the `head` plugin i can see them listed under "po"

```
{
    "query": {
        "range": {
            "po.vendorStatuses.estimatedShipDate": {
                "gte": "2016-10-01",
                "lte": "2016-11-01",
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We're using Nest version 1.7.2 in our project with elastic 1.4.5.

Here's some more info on our types:

```
//that builds our search query, contains many methods to build up the FilterContainer
public class PurchaseOrderSearchQueryBuilder 
{
    protected FilterContainer Filter { get; set; }

    public PurchaseOrderSearchQueryBuilder WithExpectedShipDate(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
    {
        var newFilter = Filter<PurchaseOrder>. 
        //method i need to implment

        Filter &= newFilter;

        return this;
    }
}

//example working filter method
public PurchaseOrderSearchQueryBuilder WithCustomerId(long customerId)
{
    if (customerId > 0)
        Filter &= Filter && Filter<PurchaseOrder>.Term(p => p.CustomerId, customerId);
    return this;
}

public class PurchaseOrder 
{
    ...
    public long CustomerId { get; set; }
    public List<PoVendorStatus> VendorStatuses { get; set; }
}

public class PoVendorStatus
{
    public long Id { get; set; } 
    ...
    public DateTime? EstimatedShipDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime StatusUpdateDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you using `ElasticSearch.Net` or `Nest`? I cannot find any static class `Filter<>` in both Namespaces.

Comment: What version of NEST are you using? And What version of Elasticsearch are you running against?

Comment: @RussCam we're using Nest version 1.7.2

Comment: @Dleh and version of Elasticsearch you are targeting? Also, latest `PurchaseOrder` by `EstimatedShipDate` out of _all_ `PurchaseOrder`s? Is `List<VendorStatus` mapped as a nested type? Can you show the mapping in Elasticsearch for `PurchaseOrder`?

Comment: We have a much more complex filter that is being created, this is just one aspect of it.  We are limited to Elastic 1.4.5. I'll provide some more info on my question

Answer (score 2):

Using nest this will return all the parent object that have one inner object that has met the condition. If you want to query nested object as well the need to be mapped as [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/nested.html) and you need to use [nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/nested-query-usage.html).

```
//Fluent
client.Search<PurchaseOrder>(s=>s.Query(
                    q=>q.DateRange(
                        dr=>dr.Field(p=>p.VendorStatuses.First().StatusUpdateDate)
                              .GreaterThan(fromDate)
                              .LessThan(toDate))));
//Object
client.Search<PurchaseOrder>(new SearchRequest<PurchaseOrder>()
                {
                    Query =new DateRangeQuery
                    {
                        //If you used all default mappings this might be camelCase
                        Field = "VendorStatuses.StatusUpdateDate",
                        GreaterThan = fromDate,
                        LessThan = toDate
                    }
                });
```